# Rendering a component inside another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a page that includes a sidebar component, and a component that returns a list of a series of services from Firebase. I want to make it so that when the user clicks on one of the results, the listing renders another component, where they can see the details of that one service.

```
<div key={company.id} onClick={() => { return <CompanyDetails id={company.id} />}}>
   <div key={company.id} className="company-photo" ></div>
   <div className="company-info">
      <h2>{company.name}</h2>
      <p>Founded in {company.founded}</p>
   </div>    
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to return the component onClick, but it's not working. I have already created and imported the CompanyDetails component.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to set state in the click handler. Can you show us your existing state with its list and how you're using it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply returning a component won't do anything of interest.

For a simple case, you'll want to just have state that describes what to render; in general, you'll want to use a router (react-router, Reach Router, ...) to make URLs accessible too. Here's the simple case.

```
function CompanyList({ setShowDetail }) {
  return getCompaniesFromSomewhere().map(company => (
    <div key={company.id} onClick={() => setShowDetail(company.id)}>
      <div key={company.id} className="company-photo" />
      <div className="company-info">
        <h2>{company.name}</h2>
        <p>Founded in {company.founded}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
}

function CompanyDetails({ id }) {
  return <>Company ID {id}</>;
}

function App() {
  const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = React.useState();
  if (showDetail) {
    return <CompanyDetails id={showDetail} />;
  }
  return <CompanyList setShowDetail={setShowDetail} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That does it. I'll just have to make some refactoring now.